# Indian passport expiring - Travel to Canada

Tags: canada, india

My mother would be traveling to Canada from March to June 2020 on Indian passport and Canadian visitor Visa.

However, both passport and Visa would expire in July 2020.

Can she travel with existing documents or does she need to get it renewed?

Answer (score 0):

You can enter Canada at any time on or before the expiry date of the *visa*.

You must exit Canada on or before the expiry date of the *passport*, if you were not given a shorter admission time by the CBSA border officials. Typically the admission is for six months, but it will be reduced to the validity of the passport if it is about to expire.